# Is there a closed form for the sum of product of AP series raised to some power k?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Is there a closed form for the following kind of exhaustive sum of product of $n$ AP series numbers starting from any first integer $\ge 1$ and common difference $\ge 1$?

For a given positive integer $Q$, it has set $Y$ is ordered tuples of $n$ positive integers $>=0$ that adds to $n$. I want to find out the sum of product of the $n$ AP series numbers raised to the corresponding ordered tuples number in the above set $Y$.

$\sum\limits_{Y} \prod\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i^{y_i}}$

where $Y$ is set of all possible ordered tuples of $y_i$ such that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^ n y_i = q$ for $q$ $\epsilon$ $[0, Q]$.
Also, $y_i >= 0$.

Please see the following example for clarity.

For example,
say, first term is $a = 2$, with command difference $d=1$, and $n=3$, then the three terms will be $[2, 3, 4]$.

So for $Q = 0: $ $Y$ is $ \{(0, 0, 0)\}$

Hence, expression would evaluate to $(2^0*3^0*4^0) = 1$

Similarly, for $Q = 1: $ $Y$ is $ \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$

Hence, expression would evaluate to $(2^1*3^0*4^0) + (2^0*3^1*4^0) + (2^0*3^0*4^1)= 9$

Similarly, for $Q = 2: $ $Y$ is $ \{(2, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)\}$

Hence, expression would evaluate to $(2^2*3^0*4^0) + (2^0*3^2*4^0) + (2^0*3^0*4^2) + (2^1*3^1*4^0) + (2^0*3^1*4^1) + (2^1*3^0*4^1) = 4 + 9 + 16 + 6 + 12 + 8 = 55$

and so on for any positive value of $Q$.

Currently, I am trying to do it in a brute way. That is, for the given $Q$, I generate the set $Y$, and calculate the product terms one by one and then finally add them up. But this is very computationally intensive.

So I thought there must be some closed form, since all $n$ terms are related and in an arithmetic progression.

Unfortuanately, even after spending days and working out examples, I couldn't find any patterns.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Just compute the generating function and the rest would follow.  In other words, given your nonconstant AP $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$, extract the coefficient of $t^Q$ in
$$
(1+a_1t+a_1^2t^2+\dots)(1+a_2t+a_2t^2+\dots)\dots(1+a_nt+a_n^2t^2+\dots)=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac1{1-a_jt}.
$$
Taking partial fractions decomposition
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n\frac1{1-a_jt}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{c_j}{1-a_jt}
$$
we see the coefficient of $t^Q$ is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n c_j a_j^Q.
$$

---

**Edit**: If you want to compute it for small $Q$ and arbitrary $n$, then probably the best way is to compute the power sum by Bernoulli polynomials
$$
p_k:=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^k=d^k\frac{B_{k+1}(\frac{a_1}d+n)-B_{k+1}(\frac{a_1}d)}{k+1}
$$
and use [Newton's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#A_variant_using_complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomials) to calculate the $h_k$, $k\leq Q$
$$
kh_k=\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1}h_{k-i}p_i
$$
The value you want is $h_Q$.  The first few are

| $k$ | $B_{k+1}(x)$ | $p_k$ | $h_k$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $x-\frac12$ | $n$ | $1$ |
| $1$ | $x^2-x+\frac16$ | $na_1+\frac12n(n-1)d$ | $na_1+\frac12n(n-1)d$ |
| $2$ | $x^3-\frac32x^2+\frac12x$ | $na_1^2+n(n-1)a_1d+\frac16n(n-1)(2n-1)d^2$ | $\frac12n(n+1)a_1^2+\frac12n(n-1)(n+1)a_1d+\frac1{24}n(n-1)(n+1)(3n-2)d^2$ |
| $3$ | $x^4-2x^3+x^2-\frac1{30}$ | $na_1^3+\frac123n(n-1)a_1^2d+\frac12n(n-1)(2n-1)a_1d^2+\frac14n^2(n-1)^2d^3$ | $\frac16n(n+1)(n+2)a_1^3+\frac14n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)a_1^2d+\frac1{24}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(3n-2)a_1d^2+\frac1{48}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)d^3$ |
| $4$ | $x^5-\frac52x^4+\frac53x^3-\frac16x$ | $na_1^4+2n(n-1)a_1^3d+n(n-1)(2n-1)a_1^2d^2+n^2(n-1)^2a_1d^3+\frac1{30}n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^2-3n-1)d^4$ | $\frac1{24}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)a_1^4+\frac1{12}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)a_1^3d+\frac1{48}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(3n-2)a_1^2d^2+\frac1{48}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)a_1d^3+\frac1{5760}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(15n^3-15n^2-10n+8)d^4$ |
| $5$ | $x^6-3x^5+\frac52x^4-\frac12x^2+\frac1{42}$ | $na_1^5+\frac125n(n-1)a_1^4d+\frac135n(n-1)(2n-1)a_1^3d^2+\frac125n^2(n-1)^2a_1^2d^3+\frac16n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^2-3n-1)a_1d^4+\frac1{12}n^2(n-1)^2(2n^2-2n-1)d^5$ | $\frac1{120}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)a_1^5+\frac1{48}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)a_1^4d+\frac1{144}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(3n-2)a_1^3d^2+\frac1{96}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)a_1^2d^3+\frac1{5760}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(15n^3-15n^2-10n+8)a_1d^4+\frac1{11520}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(3n^2+n-6)d^5$ |
| $6$ | $x^7-\frac72x^6+\frac72x^5-\frac76x^3+\frac16x$ | $na_1^6+3n(n-1)a_1^5d+\frac125n(n-1)(2n-1)a_1^4d^2+5n^2(n-1)^2a_1^3d^3+\frac12n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^2-3n-1)a_1^2d^4+\frac12n^2(n-1)^2(2n^2-2n-1)a_1d^5+\frac1{42}n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^4-6n^3+3n+1)d^6$ | $\frac1{720}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)a_1^6+\frac1{240}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)a_1^5d+\frac1{576}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(3n-2)a_1^4d^2+\frac1{288}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)a_1^3d^3+\frac1{11520}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(15n^3-15n^2-10n+8)a_1^2d^4+\frac1{11520}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(3n^2+n-6)a_1d^5+\frac1{2903040}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(63n^5-315n^3+224n^2+140n-96)d^6$ |
| $7$ | $x^8-4x^7+\frac{14}3x^6-\frac73x^4+\frac23x^2-\frac1{30}$ | $na_1^7+\frac127n(n-1)a_1^6d+\frac127n(n-1)(2n-1)a_1^5d^2+\frac1435n^2(n-1)^2a_1^4d^3+\frac167n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^2-3n-1)a_1^3d^4+\frac147n^2(n-1)^2(2n^2-2n-1)a_1^2d^5+\frac16n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^4-6n^3+3n+1)a_1d^6+\frac1{24}n^2(n-1)^2(3n^4-6n^3-n^2+4n+2)d^7$ | $\frac1{5040}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)a_1^7+\frac1{1440}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)a_1^6d+\frac1{2880}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(3n-2)a_1^5d^2+\frac1{1152}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)a_1^4d^3+\frac1{34560}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(15n^3-15n^2-10n+8)a_1^3d^4+\frac1{23040}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(3n^2+n-6)a_1^2d^5+\frac1{2903040}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(63n^5-315n^3+224n^2+140n-96)a_1d^6+\frac1{5806080}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(9n^4+18n^3-57n^2-34n+80)d^7$ |
| $8$ | $x^9-\frac92x^8+6x^7-\frac{21}5x^5+2x^3-\frac3{10}x$ | $na_1^8+4n(n-1)a_1^7d+\frac1314n(n-1)(2n-1)a_1^6d^2+14n^2(n-1)^2a_1^5d^3+\frac137n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^2-3n-1)a_1^4d^4+\frac1314n^2(n-1)^2(2n^2-2n-1)a_1^3d^5+\frac132n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^4-6n^3+3n+1)a_1^2d^6+\frac13n^2(n-1)^2(3n^4-6n^3-n^2+4n+2)a_1d^7+\frac1{90}n(n-1)(2n-1)(5n^6-15n^5+5n^4+15n^3-n^2-9n-3)d^8$ | $\frac1{40320}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)a_1^8+\frac1{10080}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)a_1^7d+\frac1{17280}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(3n-2)a_1^6d^2+\frac1{5760}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)a_1^5d^3+\frac1{138240}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(15n^3-15n^2-10n+8)a_1^4d^4+\frac1{69120}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(3n^2+n-6)a_1^3d^5+\frac1{5806080}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(63n^5-315n^3+224n^2+140n-96)a_1^2d^6+\frac1{5806080}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(9n^4+18n^3-57n^2-34n+80)a_1d^7+\frac1{1393459200}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(135n^7+315n^6-1575n^5-735n^4+5320n^3-2820n^2-1936n+1152)d^8$ |
| $9$ | $x^{10}-5x^9+\frac{15}2x^8-7x^6+5x^4-\frac32x^2+\frac5{66}$ | $na_1^9+\frac129n(n-1)a_1^8d+6n(n-1)(2n-1)a_1^7d^2+21n^2(n-1)^2a_1^6d^3+\frac1521n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^2-3n-1)a_1^5d^4+\frac1221n^2(n-1)^2(2n^2-2n-1)a_1^4d^5+2n(n-1)(2n-1)(3n^4-6n^3+3n+1)a_1^3d^6+\frac123n^2(n-1)^2(3n^4-6n^3-n^2+4n+2)a_1^2d^7+\frac1{10}n(n-1)(2n-1)(5n^6-15n^5+5n^4+15n^3-n^2-9n-3)a_1d^8+\frac1{20}n^2(n-1)^2(n^2-n-1)(2n^4-4n^3-n^2+3n+3)d^9$ | $\frac1{362880}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)a_1^9+\frac1{80640}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)a_1^8d+\frac1{120960}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)(3n-2)a_1^7d^2+\frac1{34560}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)a_1^6d^3+\frac1{691200}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)(15n^3-15n^2-10n+8)a_1^5d^4+\frac1{276480}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)(3n^2+n-6)a_1^4d^5+\frac1{17418240}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)(63n^5-315n^3+224n^2+140n-96)a_1^3d^6+\frac1{11612160}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)(9n^4+18n^3-57n^2-34n+80)a_1^2d^7+\frac1{1393459200}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)(135n^7+315n^6-1575n^5-735n^4+5320n^3-2820n^2-1936n+1152)a_1d^8+\frac1{2786918400}n^2(n-1)^2(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)(n+8)(15n^6+75n^5-135n^4-527n^3+768n^2+668n-1008)d^9$ |

Comment: How to compute $c_j$?

Comment: Compute the partial fraction decomposition, or equivalent methods.

Comment: Re your comment on a mathSE question that was recently deleted, re my embedding the image directly into the question.  That was a very interesting insight that never occurred to me.

Comment: @user10354138 is there a way to remove the $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n$ dependency in  $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n c_j a_j^Q$ since that we know they are in AP?

Comment: Knowing they are in AP only changes $\sum_{j=1}^n c_ja_j^Q$ to $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j(a+(j-1)d)^Q$ and $c_j$ has some simplifications.

Comment: @user10354138 yes, did some simplifications using that expansion, but still complexity remains $O(n)$ for each $Q$. I was thinking if there is a way to make it $O(1)$ or at least  $O(log n)$ per $Q$ using the AP property. I tried to simplify the above expression using $a+(j-1)d$, but at some point the expression became unmanageable for me.

Comment: Well, if $Q\ll n$, then you can just play with Bernoulli polynomials, Newton-Girard, and the identity $\sum_{i=0}^Q (-1)^i e_i h_{Q-i}$ relating complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials and elementary symmetric polynomials.  That will trade $O(n)$ to $O(Q^2)$ or something like that, because that requires the answer to all previous $Q$'s to be computed.

Comment: Edited to add large $n$ small (fixed-ish) $Q$.